# How to get local file in HTML when using JSP and Java

Tags: java, html, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I'm running a Java web application using Tomcat and I've got my Java classes and .jsp files rendering the web. I am trying to implement a feature where you search for key words within files and then return the files so the user can download them from the webpage.

I want to store the files within a local directory, as the server will eventually be running off a local Linux machine. However, I am unable to get the path to the file to work on the HTML side. In Java I can easily do :

```
final File file = new File("/home/user/resources");
```

Which will find the files in there. However, in HTML I've been trying various URL's, including:

```
a href="/home/user/resource" download>"Name"</a>
```

However it cannot find the file, I gather this is because it's looking within the web application.

So, my question is. How can I get the HTML side to find the same files, in the same location as Java? If it's not possible without storing the files within the web app, is there a way to serve up the file from the Java side and make it available to HTML?

Also, the files I'll be storing will most likely be Word files, .doc and .docx.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Let me know if you need any more info.

EDIT : Updated download link within the .jsp file and within <% %> tags.

```
<a href="file:///home/simon/resources/clientInfo/" + entry.getValue() + "\" download>" + entry.getValue() + "</a>
```

Chrome complains of a network error.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [file scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme). Without the file scheme the browser assumes that your file is relative to the webpage and tries to resolve the file by making a request to your webapp.The file or link needs file:/// added before the your jsp's <%=path%> variable, so that the browser knows it needs to open a local file on the user's machine.

> Sample link

```
<a href="file:///<%=path%>">click here</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've just tried putting that in, but it doesn't seem to be working. I'm sure I'm just doing something syntactically wrong. I've added my download link to the question.